# Grafana-Loki move instance by copy bucket

Tags: minio, grafana-loki

I was install Loki in multi tenant mode, for persistent data it have Minio. It works fine, but i need to move it to diffretn storage, so I did bucket, copy all files from old bucket and create new instance of loki witch point on new bucket. After connect to grafana bouth Loki instances, newone was empty.

Loki have some procedure to import data from bucket?